# Why am i getting [Object Promise], how to work with a promise

Tags: api, vue.js, asynchronous, async-await, axios

I am new to  Vue.js and Axios. Working with a promise always confuses me.

Can anyone guide me here. I am calling an API looking for an access_token.

I want to store this token and use it in a separate different API call.

I have tried variations of axios, fetch, request, syn-request. Axios is what i want to use.

```
<template>
   <div class="col-xs-6">
      <label>Access Token:</label>
      <input type="text" name="name1" v-model="token">
  </div>
</template>
<script>

import axios from 'axios'

/* eslint-disable */
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      token: ''
    }
  },
  mounted () {
    this.token = this.displayAccessToken()
    console.log('token:'+this.token)
  },
  methods: {
    displayAccessToken(){
      function getAccessToken(){
        return axios({
          method: 'POST',
          'url': 'my_api_end_point',
          'auth': {
            'username': 'my_username',
            'password': 'my_password'
          },
          'headers': {
            'content-type': 'application/json'
          }
        }).then(function(response) {
          console.log('response:' + response)
          return response.data.access_token;
        });
      }

      async function saveToken(){
        let output = await getAccessToken()
        return output
      }

     return saveToken();
    }
  }
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are overcomplicating the response fetching process. See if the following adjustments help, and please be sure to only call the next APIs subsequently (right after this `token` is set), that is when the first `Promise` is resolved.

```js
export default {
  data () {
    return {
      token: ''
    }
  },

  async mounted () {
    await this.displayAccessToken();

    console.log('token:' + this.token);
  },

  methods: {
    async displayAccessToken() {
      this.token = await axios({
        method: 'POST',
        'url': 'my_api_end_point',
        'auth': {
          'username': 'my_username',
          'password': 'my_password'
        },
        'headers': {
          'content-type': 'application/json'
        }
      })
      .then(function(response) {
        console.log('response:' + response);

        return response.data.access_token;
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Also, if all this method does is returning a token, I would probably make it a void function and call the method `setAccessToken` instead, but of course that would depend on your use case.